# Why does MySQLDump write data to the terminal when importing/restoring a file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore/import a MySQLdump file using the following command (on Windows, version 5.x.x):

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases < myfile.sql
```

However, in the middle of processing, the command prompt window starts beeping like crazy. Is it possible to remove the output of the mysqldump command (which I'm assuming is what is causing this sound to occur)? The file in question is slightly more than 200MB.

I've looked at the flags and only seems to be --verbose that would help me. However, it seems that it wouldn't be able to stop the output in the command prompt window (but add more output?).

**Edit #1**

One answer, that has been removed, suggested piping the output /dev/null. I'm on Windows and I have no idea what would be the equivalent. If I pipe it to an actual file, I would be in effect almost duplicating my dump to another file? **Why is the restore outputting to the prompt in the first place?**

Comment: @MattBall I can't as it's the case speaker that goes off... testing one of the answers now...

Comment: "starts beeping like crazy" sounds like the [*BEL/Bell* character (ASCII 7)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) is being written to the terminal. Many terminals will emit a "beep" when this occurs (e.g. `cat /dev/urandom` should result in similar behavior as *garbage* is written to the terminal). The question to ask is thus *why* is the data written to the terminal -- and where *should* it go?

Comment: You typed a *comesfrom* instead of a *gozinta*. Think of it as a funnel, and your funnel is going the wrong way.

Comment: @pst I have no idea why it's written to the terminal. I'm following what many tutorials out there seem to indicate are the steps to import a file into MySQL. Whenever I import data and it's starts making sounds, colleagues ridicule me stating that I broke the network... LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you really intend to run

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > myfile.sql
```

(your redirection is the wrong way around)

mysqldump writes out to a file.  To import from that file, you would use

```
mysql -u root -p < myfile.sql
```

Comment: You are correct in your directions. However, since I intend to restore/import a file, my direction seems to be correct (ie. less than).

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus: You don't use *mysqldump* to restore/import.  You use *mysql* to do the restore/import, using the file originally exported by *mysqldump*.

Comment: Ahh... didn't notice the use of mysql instead of mysqldump.  That indeed works! Thanks! I also apologize for not having read more carefully.